# How to filter in ng-repeat in a specific field but passing it an array, knowing that the field may or may not be contained in the array? Angular 1.5

Tags: html, angularjs, multidimensional-array, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
ng-repeat="equipment in equipments | filter: {guidEquiment: ['cb8b22e1-43f0-4dc9-b2dc-34847731e2d1','cb8b22e1-43f0-4dc9-b2dc-34847731e2d1','cb8b22e1-43f0-4dc9-b2dc-34847731e2d1',....N]}"
```

Where

```
equipment = {
    guidEquiment: 'cb8b22e1-43f0-4dc9-b2dc-34847731e2d1'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a custom filter by passing the necessary id's array, but not in the html, look at the working demo.

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("listController", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {

    $scope.equipments = [{
      "guidEquiment": "96a70488-f67e-4445-a303-7629d24ff829",
      "equipname": "Toughjoyfax"
    }, {
      "guidEquiment": "b17f86fc-afb8-429e-82b1-bc0e9a96c039",
      "equipname": "Fix San"
    }, {
      "guidEquiment": "d4bcd011-f6c4-4d18-a6b2-01e89aeef2bc",
      "equipname": "Tempsoft"
    }];
    
    $scope.filterBy = ["b17f86fc-afb8-429e-82b1-bc0e9a96c039", "96a70488-f67e-4445-a303-7629d24ff829"];

  }
]);
app.filter('inArray', function($filter) {
  return function(list, arrayFilter, element) {
    if (arrayFilter) {
      return $filter("filter")(list, function(listItem) {
        return arrayFilter.indexOf(listItem[element]) != -1;
      });
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.5/cosmo/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

  <script data-require="jquery@1.11.3" data-semver="1.11.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.7" data-semver="1.4.7" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app='app' ng-controller="listController">
  <div ng-repeat="equipment in equipments |  inArray:filterBy:'guidEquiment'">
    <h1> {{equipment.equipname}}</h1>
    
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The intention was to be able to pass the array as a filter in the Html, since I already have the filter working with 2 parameters


A normal string on a Name field and another where I look for an array if there is one of the possibilities selected, so far these filters work together and I have the third parameter where I should look for the field guidEquipment, the problem is that I must search all The equipment that is contained in the array of guidEquipment, anyway thank you ..

I will try with the code provided as the third parameter, to have that results.

Comment: $scope.equipments = [{
      "activityTypes":['guid1', 'guid2', 'etc'],
      "tag": "string",
      "guidEquiment": "96a70488-f67e-4445-a303-7629d24ff829",
      "equipname": "Toughjoyfax"
    }, {
"activityTypes":['guid1', 'guid2', 'etc'],
      "tag": "string",
      "guidEquiment": "b17f86fc-afb8-429e-82b1-bc0e9a96c039",
      "equipname": "Fix San"
    }, {
"activityTypes":['guid3', 'guid5', 'etc'],
      "tag": "string",
      "guidEquiment": "d4bcd011-f6c4-4d18-a6b2-01e89aeef2bc",
      "equipname": "Tempsoft"
    }];


where modelselectedtype = 'guid1';